# Extract a number and a string in specific rows in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

I have a df made by a single column, structured like this:

```
      V  
 I-232 0 CAT
 G-435 1 DOG
 X-212 AIR
```

i want to create a new DF made like this:

```
    N   V
    0  CAT
    1  DOG
```

So, i want to extract only **those rows which contain 0 or 1** and the **text after them**, creating a new DF (2 columns), the first made by those index (0/1) and the correspondent following words on the other column.

How could i do?

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of alternatives, here's a version with regex in base R:

```
x <- c("I-232 0 CAT","G-435 1 DOG","X-212 AIR")
my_regex <- "^.* (1|0) (.*)$"
partial <- regmatches(x, regexec(my_regex, x))

df <- as.data.frame( Reduce( rbind, partial[ sapply(partial, length) > 0 ] )[,2:3],"")
```

Giving:

```
> df
  V1  V2
1  0 CAT
2  1 DOG
```

The idea is to match and make groups of desired values in one pass with the regex `"^.* (1|0) (.*)$"` which match start of string, anything until "a space followed by 1 or 0 itself followed by a space" and anything the end of line. In the process it captures in first group `()` the alternative 1 or 0 and the remaining text after the space in a second group.

`regmatches` output is as follow:

```
> regmatches(x,regexec(my_regex,x))
[[1]]
[1] "I-232 0 CAT" "0"           "CAT"        

[[2]]
[1] "G-435 1 DOG" "1"           "DOG"        

[[3]]
character(0)
```

so we filter this result to exclude empty lines with `partial[ sapply(partial,length) > 0 ]` we then ask `Reduce` to `rbind` each entry of the list and turn it into a data.frame with `as.data.frame` (the last `""` parameter is to avoid row names induced by Reduce) and we then subset this data.frame for only the two desired columns (2 and 3, our groups as regmatches return the matched text as first entry.

Answer (score 0):

```
V <- c("aaa 0 cat", "bbb 1 dog ", "ccc 2 air")
df <- data.frame(V)

> df
           V
1  aaa 0 cat
2 bbb 1 dog 
3  ccc 2 air
```

You could use the dplyr and tidyr packages

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- separate(df, V, c("txt", "ind", "txt2"), sep = " ")
df3 <- filter(df2, ind %in% 0:1)
df4 <- select(df3, ind, txt2)

> df4
  ind txt2
1   0  CAT
2   1  DOG
```

Or with pipe

```
df %>% 
  separate(V, c("txt", "ind", "txt2"), sep = " ") %>%
  filter(ind %in% 0:1) %>% 
  select(-txt)
```

Comment: This is only an example.my DF is made by 700 rows and only one column.

Comment: This does not work since the OP's dataframe has a single column

Comment: Try with a single column and only 2 values for last field, not 3 in each. I'm unsure how separate handle missing values. (Well, test with OP values)

Comment: I deleted mine as it is essentially the same as yours (after you edit). You can do all in one pipe `df %>% 
 separate(V, into = c('drop', 'N', 'V'), sep = ' ') %>% 
 filter(N %in% c(0, 1)) %>% 
 select(-drop)`

Comment: @Tensibai Yes, my code doesn't work with missing values.

Comment: It's very basic and readable. Either with pipe or via your way, readability is exactly the same

Comment: the machine answered me: Warning message:
Too many values at 702 locations: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,

Comment: Me too, but it's only warning and it returns me the correct output

Comment: it returns me No data available in table @MrSnake

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer with `grepl` and `strsplit`

```
x <- c("I-232 0 CAT","G-435 1 DOG","X-212 AIR")

# which elements have " 0 " or " 1 "
ind <- grepl("[[:space:]](1|0)[[:space:]]", x)

# split
res <- strsplit(x[ind], "1[[:space:]]|0[[:space:]]")

# take last element
sapply(res, function(x) x[length(x)])
```

Comment: Your first regex will match "balabhabja0 test" in fact the alternation match ` 1` or `0 `. I think you're after `"[[:space:]](1|0)[[:space:]]"`. And the regex for strsplit could be simplified with `"(1|0)[[:space:]]"` also.

Comment: Without the space before to split on, I'm afraid something like "X-210 AIR" will match and will not give proper results.

Comment: You are right - I should have tested the suggestion above.